# How to Stop Double Click

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the below code that is used to hide/unhide rows. In my spreadsheet I have a whole lot of images which are small down arrows. I've assigned the below code to those down arrows, effectively to use them to minimise and maximise rows as the spreadsheet has hundreds and hundreds of rows of data.

If I press on one down arrow it hides rows under it, then press again it unhides it, however if i press one down arrow and then another arrow the second click doesn't do anything I then have to press on it one more time to get it to work, or I have to press the original down arrow again. It's obviously due to cell A1 containing x. Is there any way to fix this?

```
Sub Advertising_20_21()
     If Range("A1") = "x" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "x"
    ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear what your issue is. Can you provide a [mcve]? Your code works as expected for me. If A1 contains `x` it hides the row if not it shows the row. I don't see any issue here.

Comment: Is this not pretty much using Outline/Group view on the Rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if the row is hidden directly rather than the value of A1 (which I assume is shared by all your arrow procedures and is therefore, the source of your undesired behaviour)

```
Sub Advertising_20_21()
  If Not ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21").EntireRow.Hidden Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "x"
    ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
  End If
End Sub
```

The following is a slightly better approach

```
Sub ToggleHiddenRow(rng As Range)
  With rng.EntireRow
    .Hidden = Not .Hidden
  End With
End Sub

Sub ToggleAdvertising_20_21()
  ToggleHiddenRow ActiveSheet.Range("Advertising_20_21")
End With
```

Comment: Thanks soo much Symmetry, works like a charm. Muchly appreciated :D